# AppCenter support for Kotlin Gradle DSL (build.gradle.kts) and multi module app

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, visual-studio-app-center

I'd like to use AppCenter to do the building of apk for specific app module with the project setup with Kotlin Gradle DSL, currently the AppCenter complaint that **We couldn’t find any Android projects in your branch.**

Listed reason is

- I used Kotlin Gradle DSL which I think the AppCenter didn't yet support(Please correct me if Im wrong)
- I used multi module app which the AppCenter is confused which App Module should they used

Multi App Module structure is like below and for example I want to build the 2nd app module in AppCenter

```
- Project
--- application-modules
----- app1
----- app2
----- app3

--- library-modules
----- *****
----- *****
```

Is there anyone here that implement the same way I do ?
Can anyone provide any documentation regarding the same problem I have ?
Any comment is acceptable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your .gitignore file in the root of your project folder, you need to remove some lines, so that you check in these files. You must do this, to enable AppCenter to detect your Android app. If you don’t, AppCenter will not be able to find your Android app, and not be able to build.

```
# Android related
[REMOVE THIS LINE] **/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
[REMOVE THIS LINE]**/android/gradlew
[REMOVE THIS LINE]**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
```

https://buildflutter.com/deploying-flutter-apps-via-appcenter/

After pushing to your repo, you will see your module on AppCenter.

Comment: I have the same problem even if I remove these lines. I believe that they really doesn't support Gradle DSL (which is shame)